# Javascript getting ignored because of Response.Redirect()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on asp.net using C# and I need to show a message box and confirm the input from user and redirect to another page, my code is something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    sb.Append("if (confirm('YES OR NO?')){ /*some javascript code*/ }");
    sb.Append("</script>");

    Page.RegisterStartupScript("FocusScript", sb.ToString());
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

}
```

here the problem is directly getting redirected to next page without showing message box. 
if i remove `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");` it shows message box successfully. I think the here may be is `Response.Redirect()` has higher precedence compared to `javascript`

I tried using

```
sb.Append("if (confirm('YES OR NO?')){ window.location.href = \"Default.aspx"; }\");
```

instead of using `Response.Redirect()` but page didn't got redirected,  what should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does the Button1 placed in UpdatePanel? If so, use the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method instead

Comment: Fyi, it's `type="text/javascript"` and not `language="..."`

Comment: check ur backslashes. I think it might be like this:
sb.Append("if (confirm('YES OR NO?')){ window.location.href = \"Default.aspx\"; }");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option of using adding javascript in client click event

eg:-

```
<asp:button id="Button1" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and then in the code side simple redirect the page.

Comment: `javascript:` shouldn't be used on events. All it does is define a label.

Answer (score 6):

Do you absolutely need to handle this on the server side? Indeed this is where quite a simple thing is getting confusing.

If you could, for instance, handle it with Javascript / jQuery, you could do something simple like:

```
$('#Button1').click(function(){
   if (confirm("Yes or No?")){
      window.location = "/default.aspx";
   }
});
```

Comment: Absolutely. There's no need to use `RegisterStartupScript` just because you use ASP .NET. The behavior described is purely *client-side*.

Answer (score 1):

`Confirm` is a JavaScript function and it executes on client side. After you register it, you immediately redirect to another page, and so the function is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

add following code on `Page_Load`

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(confirm('do you want to redirect?')){}else{return false}");
```

now ur button click will first trigger java confirmation modal box.

as for ur Button1 click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

The idea is - your codebehind Button1_Click event will be triggered only after user confirms  by clicking OK

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to add an attribute to the button at page load and leave the button_click function to just redirect. Something like this (Page Load):

```
button.attribute.add("onclick","Javascript:confirmFunction();")
```

in button click just have this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");    
}
```

finally in JS have this:

```
<script>
function confirmFunction()
{
    if(Confirm("Yes OR NO") 
       //Add your JS Code
       return true; //will pass onto server
    else
       //Add your JS Code
       return false; //will not go to server
}
</script>
```

HTH